# Conditional Formatting Specific Text Containing A Work

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a script that works perfect to add a conditional formatting statement to match a specific work.  In the below I modify the xlCellValue -> xlTextString, but when I look up valid operator all I see is (xlBetween, xlEqual, xlGreater, xlGreaterEqual, xlLess, xlLessEqual, xlNotBetween, or xlNotEqual) but not a "Contains".  Looking for help on how to accomplish this.

```
Sub CondFormat_01String(strRange, strString1, intColorIndex1, blnStopIfTrue)
  
    Dim Rg As Range
    Dim cond1, cond2 As FormatCondition ', cond2 As FormatCondition
    Set Rg = Range(strRange)
    
    'Define the rule for each conditional format
    Set cond1 = Rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, strString1)

    'Define the format applied for each conditional format
    With cond1
        .Interior.ColorIndex = intColorIndex1
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
    End With
    
    Rg.FormatConditions(Rg.FormatConditions.Count).StopIfTrue = blnStopIfTrue
    
End Sub
```

Basically what I am trying to do is the following with VBA

[image: 1]

From Micorsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add

Looked up type options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlformatconditiontype
looked up Operator options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlformatconditionoperator

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while setting up the CF on a cell?  It will show you something like `Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="blah", TextOperator:=xlContains`

Comment: FYI here `Dim cond1, cond2 As FormatCondition` only `cond2` is a `FormatCondition`: `cond1` is the default `Variant` type.

Answer (score 1):

From comment above:

```
Sub Tester()
    CondFormat_01String "A13", "blah", 3, True
End Sub

Sub CondFormat_01String(strRange, strString1, intColorIndex1, blnStopIfTrue)
    'best to be explicit about which worksheet you're operating on
    With ActiveSheet.Range(strRange).FormatConditions.Add( _
           Type:=xlTextString, String:="blah", TextOperator:=xlContains)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = intColorIndex1
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
        .StopIfTrue = blnStopIfTrue
    End With
End Sub
```